# Шифрование Triple DES

Tags: java, криптография

Есть ключ зашифрованный Triple DES на C# 16 байт. Необходимо расшифровать в коде написанном на Java, но Triple DES на java из документации следует:

> Keysize must be equal to 112 or 168

Вопрос это реально или нет? Необходимо расшифровать и зашифровать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну все правильно.

1. Ключ у TripleDES или 112 или 168 битов
2. Размер блока 64 бита (шифрование ведется блоками по 64 бита)
3. Исходный шифр 2 байта (128 бит)
4. Отсюда следует что у вас есть 2 блока по 64 бита, следовательно там зашифрован ключ длиной 112 бит.

Поясняю: 112 бит дают 2 блока по 64 бита, из которых 64*2-112=16 бит заполнены согласно выбранному алгоритму выравнивания.

Вам нужно определить [алгоритм выравнивания](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) - обычно PKCS#5 или PKCS#7

[Алгоритм сцепления блоков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) скорее всего [ECB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80#%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8) (на малом количестве блоков обычно не снисходят до CBC)

Попробуйте так:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("TripleDES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
```

Comment: Большое спасибо